# allowTouchScrolling: true not working for my fabricjs canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I've got a canvas that I want to be scrollable on mobile.

So I added this to the canvas instance: `allowTouchScrolling: true`. Like this:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
    allowTouchScrolling: true
});
canvas.allowTouchScrolling = true;
```

I know it's double but I figured I'd try both ways, unfortunately both ways don't work.

Codepen of the canvas: https://codepen.io/twan2020/pen/dyOLJOz

You can scroll the scrollbars, but you cannot scroll or drag from within the canvas. Why?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using version 2 or higher (I used 4.5.0) then you should update the fabric js library.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/annZm.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHLOo.png)

Source:- https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/pull/5904/commits/50962efe6bbd77174cda2e9bd169c19d301edb7a

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question, but how exactly update the fabric js library?